# Guardar ID en tabla relacionada desde la tabla principal

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mvc

Tengo tres tablas en mi base de datos:

[image: BDD]

En un principio, solo tenía a la tabla `contratos` y recientemente necesitaba agregar a las otras dos tablas, como verán, hay un campo en `pagos` el cual esta relacionado `contratos` por `fk`.

Y necesito que, cuando esté en mi parte de agregar un "contrato", este guarde su ID de su tabla (`contratos`) en la tabla `pagos`. Así que sería como enviar a guardar datos en dos tablas a la vez.
Aquí esta mi código del controlador:

```
function agregar_contrato()
{
    $data = array(
        'contratos' => $this->Pagos_model->getContratos(),
    );
    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/clientes/agregar_contrato", $data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
}

function registro_contrato()
{
    $fecha_de_contrato    = $this->input->post("fecha_de_contrato");
    $fecha_de_instalacion = $this->input->post("fecha_de_instalacion");
    $fecha_de_corte       = $this->input->post("fecha_de_corte");
    $fecha_de_pago        = $this->input->post("fecha_de_pago");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("fecha_de_contrato", "\"Fecha del contrato\"", "trim|required");

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data = array(
            'fecha_de_contrato'    => $fecha_de_contrato,
            'fecha_de_instalacion' => $fecha_de_instalacion,
            'fecha_de_corte'       => $fecha_de_corte,
            'fecha_de_pago'        => $fecha_de_pago,
            'borrado'              => "1",
        );

        if ($this->Clientes_model->save_contrato($data)) {
            redirect(base_url() . "clientes/clientes_controller"); //Me regresa a la vista principal

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "No se pudo guardar la informacion");
            redirect(base_url() . "clientes/clientes_controller/agregar_contrato");
        }
    } else {
        $this->agregar_contrato();
    }
}
```

Y mi modelo:

```
function getContratos()
{
    $this->db->select("con.*, pag.*, fpagos.*");
    $this->db->from("contratos con");
    $this->db->join("pagos pag", "pag.contrato_id = con.id_contratos_d");
    $this->db->join("fechas_de_pagos fpagos", "fpagos.pagos_id = pag.id_pagos");
    $this->db->where("con.borrado", "1");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Como mencioné en un principio `contratos` estaba ahí, y todo los datos los guarda bien (aquí solo he puesto 4 datos, realmente son más de 20). Pero pido ayuda, ya que lo he intentado creo seria **peor** ponerlo aquí. Así que, para evitar peores críticas, lo dejo como en un principio lo tenía.

Comment: ¿Has tratado de añadir un campo que te sirva como token, para identificar el nuevo registro que insertas en la tabla Contratos? Puedes hacer la inserción en Contratos, guardando el token, luego consultas la tabla por el token para obtener id_contratos_d y luego lo insertas en el registro de Pagos

Comment: No se me había ocurrido... Buena analogía, aunque a mi poco entendiendo:  no sería más fácil no hacer el token y solo hacer la consulta desde contratos para la sección de pagos, como vez esa opción? O no contaría como opción :)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Te estás complicando mucho. Si lo que quieres es simplemente tener un mismo campo en dos tablas:

- Primero guarda la información del contrato.
- En tu formulario de agregar pagos, **mandas a traer todos los id de los contratos disponibles** (crea una lista dropdown que te los muestre).
- Seleccionas el id del contrato deseado en el formulario de agregar pagos.
- Y guardas el nuevo pago.

Aqui viene un ejemplo base que te puede ayudar en la sección dropdown list: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

O busca otros en internet.